Typescript: Typing return for a "retry function" using .call
If I'm passing a typed function to Function.prototype.call, is there a way to infer the return type from the passed function?
Below I would expect response to be typed based on someTypedFunction return type, but instead is unknown. Are there generics for .call? Or would should I type it as any and set the type of the response?
function getNewToken(): number {
   return Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
}

//Wrapper - Outside Parent Class
async function retryOnce<R>(this: any, fn: () => R): Promise<R> {
   let isRetry = false;
   const execute = async () => {
      try{
         return await fn();
      }catch(error: any){
         if(!isRetry){
           isRetry = true;
           this.token = getNewToken();
           return execute();
         }else{
          throw Error();
         }
      }
  }
  return execute();
}

function someTypedFunction(option: string, token: number): Promise<string>{
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(token){
       return resolve(option);
    }
    return reject("No token");
  });
}

class Parent {
   token;
   constructor(token: number){
     this.token = token;
   }
   async someMethod(){
      //Usage - Inside Parent Class
      const bar = () => someTypedFunction("variable", this.token);
      const response = await retryOnce.call(this, bar);
      return response;
   }
}



I think the simultaneous generic inference on retryOnce and call is biting you here. You can instantiate retryOnce's generic if you want, as shown in this playground link, and that will work.  I'm not sure there's a great way to get inference to work otherwise. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining. Or am I missing something?

(see prev comment) I also recommend you [edit] to not use any for the this parameter of retryOnce. It should be {token: number} as shown in this playground link. This doesn't solve the problem, but it does make it harder to write call(x) for some random x that doesn't have a token.

Thank you@jcalz, I did have the Parent class assigned to this in actual code, just forgot to replicate. I think @Brother58697 was able to get me where I was trying to go. Just lots of methods to type this way so avoiding passing the Generic is ideal. Thanks again!

call is inferring its generic types from retryOnce's which isn't inferring R because it's not being directly called with bar.
One thing you can do is have retyOnce return a function with the desired functionality, that way you can call retryOnce(bar), and the returned function will have the correct return type, which call can then infer correctly.
function getNewToken(): number {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
}

//Wrapper - Outside Parent Class
function retryOnce<R>(fn: () => R): (this: Parent) => Promise<R> { // Return a new function
  return async function () {
    let isRetry = false;
    const execute = async () => {
      try {
        return await fn();
      } catch (error: any) {
        if (!isRetry) {
          isRetry = true;
          this.token = getNewToken();
          return execute();
        } else {
          throw Error();
        }
      }
    }
    return execute();
  }
}

function someTypedFunction(option: string, token: number): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (token) {
      return resolve(option);
    }
    return reject("No token");
  });
}

class Parent {
  token;
  constructor(token: number) {
    this.token = token;
  }
  async someMethod() {
    //Usage - Inside Parent Class
    const bar = () => someTypedFunction("variable", this.token);
    const response = await retryOnce(bar).call(this);
         // ^?const response: string
    return response;
  }
}

Playground

Indeed @jcalz, thank you for the catch and correction. I updated the answer. Also nice touch giving this a valid type. I used Parent instead, but OP is free to change it. (They should probably still either stick to extending a base parent class or implementing an interface )

Looks like jcalz deleted his original comment. He defined the type for this, which I hadn't done in my original answer.
